# Access AzureBlobStorage via Managed Identity c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-managed-identity

i'm wondering if there is no acutal implementation to access a blobstorage with c#  and the azure managed identity?

I know that there is a possibility to access it via the deprecated nuget package WindowsAzure.Storage 9.3.3 but it looks like that the new one one Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob 11.2.1 has this feature not yet implemented...

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Azure.Identity` library has implementations of the `TokenCredential` abstract class which can be used to authenticate clients in the `Azure.Storage.Blobs` library. The `ManagedIdentityCredential` can be used to authenticate clients on an azure host with managed identity enabled.

```cs
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri($"https://{AccountName}.blob.core.windows.net"), new ManagedIdentityCredential());
```

More information on the `Azure.Identity` library can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet).

Answer (score 2):

With `Azure.Storage.Blobs` you can do something like this:

```
public class ManagedIdentityTokenCredentials : TokenCredential
{
    private const string Resource = "https://storage.azure.com/";
    private readonly string _tenantId;

    public ManagedIdentityTokenCredentials(string tenantId)
    {
        _tenantId = tenantId;
    }

    public override async ValueTask<AccessToken> GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await new AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAuthenticationResultAsync(Resource, _tenantId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        return new AccessToken(result.AccessToken, result.ExpiresOn);
    }

    public override AccessToken GetToken(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return GetTokenAsync(requestContext, cancellationToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}

...

var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri($"https://{AccountName}.blob.core.windows.net"), new ManagedIdentityTokenCredentials(TenantId));
```